# How to fix "secure_smtplib.SMTPS.connect() missing positional argument: self" error when setting up SMTP server?

Tags: python, discord

I'm new to scripting Discord bots to send emails through SMTP. I don't know why there is an error

> TypeError: connect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

But when I change it to

> secure_smtplib.SMTPS.connect(self, host=servername, port=0)

another error that "self" isn't defined comes up. What is the problem here?

```
if message.content.startswith(">verify"):
    content = message.content.split(">") #>verify>SchAddress>Password>Subject>Body
    servername = 'smtps.gmail.com'
    password = content[2]

    #setting up email
    server = secure_smtplib.SMTPS.connect(host=servername, port=0)
    try:
      server.set_debuglevel(True)
      server.ehlo()

      if server.has_ext('STARTTLS'):
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
      
      server.login(content[1], password)
      print("logged in")

      email = send_email(content[1], content[3], content[4])
      server.send_message(email)
    finally:
      server.quit()
      print("email sent")
```

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 46, in on_message
    server = secure_smtplib.SMTPS.connect(host=servername, port=0)
TypeError: connect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Post your code an error message as text. Screenshots of text can not be accepted on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code as text. To learn why images of code are not suitable see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: What module is `secure_smtplib`?

Comment: secure_smtplib has the same functionality smtplib. So there is no difference in syntax apart from SMTP() becoming SMTPS()

Comment: I believe there is a difference but regardless, you need to pass keyword arguments when instantiating SMTPS. I can’t find any documentation around it so unless you provide the module you’re using, I can’t help further

Comment: I also do not have any documentation on it. However, the source code is https://github.com/graingert/secure-smtplib .

Answer (score 0):

`secure_smtplib.SMTPS` is a class.  You need to instantiate it.  You also probably need to override the port number.

```
server = secure_smtplib.SMTPS()
server.connect(host=servername, port=587)
```

Comment: I don't know if it worked but doing so bring up another missing positional argument error.

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 46, in on_message
    server = secure_smtplib.SMTPS()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sslkwargs'